# Sorting an array with a specific object always on top

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of persons that I would like to sort but I would like a specific name to be always the first item in the array and sort the rest.

```
persons = [{name: Mary}, {name: Adam}, {name: Boss}, {name: Peter}, {name: John}]
```

The following code sorts my array just fine:

```
let sortSelector = #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_:))
let descriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: sortSelector)
persons!.sort(using: [descriptor])
```

Result:

```
persons = [{name: Adam}, {name: Boss}, {name: John}, {name: Mary}, {name: Peter}]
```

But I would like to have `{name: Boss}` to be in first position and the sort the rest

Wished result:

```
persons = [{name: Boss}, {name: Adam}, {name: John}, {name: Mary}, {name: Peter}]
```

***Edit***
I must apologize for the confusion, I left some details out thinking my question would lead to a simple sort solution (like in js).

```
persons = NSMutableOrderedSet()
```

I populate persons from a REST:

```
self.persons?.addObjects(from: paginator!.items())
```

Which I then sort, all this works fine:

```
let sortSelector = #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_:))
let descriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: sortSelector)
persons!.sort(using: [descriptor])
```

As suggested, I've removed the object name: "Boss", then sorted and added the removed object at index 0.

When I tried to add params to the `.sort` it's throwing me a bunch of errors, I assume it's because of my use of `NSSortDescriptor`.

Comment: How did you generate the data? persons = [{name: Mary}, {name: Adam}, {name: Boss}, {name: Peter}, {name: John}]

Comment: From a REST API then load it into struct.

Comment: You shouldn't be using sort descriptors unless you're using core data

Comment: You can create a custom sort `persons.sort {
    $0.name == "Boss" ? true : $1.name == "Boss"  ? false : $0.name < $1.name
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus: No, that does not define a strict weak ordering (`x < x` must always be `false`).

Comment: @MartinR I have tested here and it works as expected regardless of the element position. Note that I have edited my comment when I realized it was wrong

Comment: @LeoDabus: It may work by chance, but is undefined behavior. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296801-sort clearly states that the predicate must be a “strict weak ordering” and in particular “areInIncreasingOrder(a, a) is always false. (Irreflexivity)”

Comment: @MartinR is it what you mean? This is in case there is duplicate elements in the array. Isn't it?

Comment: @LeoDabus: Simpler (untested, typos possible): `{  $1.name == "Boss" ? false : $0.name == "Boss" ? true : $0.name < $1.name }`

Comment: So just switch the order of the first two conditions. It was pretty close

Comment: Anyway: Moving the boss to the front after sorting might be a simpler (and easier to grasp) solution.

Comment: @MartinR is there something wrong with my answer?

Comment: @LeoDabus: I don't think so.

Answer (score 12):

You can create a custom sort predicate. If the right element is equal to "Boss" return false, if the left element is equal to "Boss" return true,  otherwise return `$0.name < $1.name`:

```
persons.sort {
    $1.name == "Boss" ? false :
    $0.name == "Boss" ? true :
    $0.name < $1.name
}
```

---

If you need a localized case insensitive sort just return `$0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.name) == .orderedAscending` at the end of your predicate:

```
persons.sort {
    $1.name == "Boss" ? false :
    $0.name == "Boss" ? true : 
    $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.name) == .orderedAscending
}
```

---

**edit/update**:

You should try to use Swift native types when coding in Swift as much as possible. No need to use `NSArray`, and/or `NSSortDescriptor`. Just use plain `Array` and native Swift sort methods. If you need a native Swift  mutable ordered set you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59887562/2303865).

---

Playground testing

```
struct Person: Hashable {
    let name: String
}

extension Person: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { name }
}

var people: OrderedSet<Person> = [.init(name: "Mary"),
                                  .init(name: "Adam"),
                                  .init(name: "Boss"),
                                  .init(name: "Peter"),
                                  .init(name: "John"),
                                  .init(name: "Boss")]

print(people)  // [Mary, Adam, Boss, Peter, John]

people.sort { $1.name == "Boss" ? false : $0.name == "Boss" ? true : $0.name < $1.name }
print(people)  // [Boss, Adam, John, Mary, Peter]
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, but this code is not something that should ever pass a CR, let alone be recommended to begineers. It's a total mess, a bunch of conditionals, no clearly visible nesting. it looks like code golf

Comment: I fully understand it, it's just much more complex than it needs to be. And took way too long to "digest" it all. Look at `sorted3` in https://repl.it/@alexandermomchilov/ExpandingOutConditionalOperators It's equivalent, but much simpler to read/parse, and much easier to understand, because the comparison of the first and second args are done together. This matches the expectations we would have, from intuiting something like ""Boss" sorts before any non-"Boss"