# How to write to an Element in a Set?

Tags: swift, set

With arrays you can use a subscript to access `Array` `Element`s directly.  You can read or write to them. With Sets I am not sure of a way to write its Elements.

For example, if I access a set element matching a condition I'm only able to read the element. It is passed by copy and I can't therefore write to the original.

For example:

```
columns.first(
    where: { 
        $0.header.last == Character(String(i))
    }
)?.cells.append(value: addValue)


// ERROR: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value
```

Comment: Why would that code work for an array?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson OP is saying that if they use an array, they can mutate it by subscript. But the set subscript (inherited from `Collection`) is get-only.

Comment: @Sweeper, exactly.

Comment: I assumed it was a struct but it's a class?

Comment: Swift Arrays and Sets are both structs not classes.

Comment: I meant the content of the Set of course.

Comment: Oh, my bad.  yes the content is a struct...Hmm.. I guess this could be a possibility if it were a class...

Comment: And that was kind of my point of my first comment but maybe I am missing something else. Anyway with a class you can do something like `set.first(where: {$0.value == 3})?.text = "d"` so in this perspective an array and a set are the same

Comment: I see that.  Its times like these when I wish I could award two answers.  I'm stalemated there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because `columns` might be a set of `struct`. So `columns.first` will give you an immutable value. If you were to use a `class`, you will get a mutable result from `columns.first` and your code will work as expected.
Otherwise, you will have to do as explained by @Sweeper in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just change things inside a set, because of [how a (hash) set works](https://victorqi.gitbooks.io/swift-algorithm/content/hash_set.html). Changing them would possibly change their hash value, making the set into an invalid state.

Therefore, you would have to take the thing you want to change out of the set, change it, then put it back.

```
if var thing = columns.first(
    where: { 
        $0.header.last == Character(String(i))
    }) {
    columns.remove(thing)
    thing.cells.append(value: addValue)
    columns.insert(thing)
}
```

If the `==` operator on `Column` doesn't care about `cells` (i.e. adding cells to a column doesn't suddenly make two originally equal columns unequal and vice versa), then you could use `update` instead:

```
if var thing = columns.first(
    where: { 
        $0.header.last == Character(String(i))
    }) {
    thing.cells.append(value: addValue)
    columns.update(thing)
}
```

As you can see, it's quite a lot of work, so maybe sets aren't a suitable data structure to use in this situation. Have you considered using an array instead? :)

```
private var _columns: [Column]
public var columns : [Column] {
    get { _columns }
    set { _columns = Array(Set(newValue)) }
    // or any other way to remove duplicate as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array-in-swift
}
```

Comment: I am using an array but I wanted to enforce no repeated elements, and I don't care about the order.

Comment: @ScottyBlades That's fine, just convert the array to a set to remove duplicates, then convert it back to an array.

Comment: Thats one way... I guess I was just hoping to strengthen the contract to the point where I can trust with certainty that any time this collection is used, there are no repeats. I guess its not possible with hash sets.

Comment: if Collumn is Equatable and it doesn't rely on cells property to differentiate between the set elements you can use update instead of removing and inserting.

Comment: Column is equatable based on its header property (not its cells). Not picturing how to apply update to this problem yet. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ScottyBlades I edited the answer an hour ago to show exactly that.

Comment: Would the inner arrays would go in a custom struct? I could encapsulate the update code  into a set extension... I think the downside to that would be the time complexity would increase relative to appending directly like I would for a class.  The downside to a class is the read write/deadlock increased risk.

Comment: Maybe the inner array would go on a custom struct called UniqueArray or something... I think that would do it.  I think I get it now.

Comment: @ScottyBlades What do you mean by the "inner arrays"? If you mean `_columns`, that could go in a property wrapper. And yes, the update code could go in a set extension. You can add a subscript that takes an `(inout Element) -> Void`.

Comment: @ScottyBlades https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887561/how-to-implement-a-mutable-ordered-set-generic-type-formerly-known-as-nsmutableo