# Conditionally conform Set to ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral protocol

Tags: swift, collections, protocols

```
protocol Weighted: Hashable {
    associatedtype D: Hashable
    associatedtype W: Hashable
    var destination: D { get }
    var weight: W { get }
    init(destination: D, weight: W)
}
```

**Approach 1**
// Edited ------------
@Dávid Pásztor has answered this part of the question, so I deleted it, to make room for more interesting second part.
// ----------------------

**Approach 2**

```
extension ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral where Self: Collection, Element: Weighted {
    init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (Element.D, Element.W)...) {
        Self.init(elements.map(Element.init))
    }
}
```

This code compiles. But the next line doesn't:

```
extension Set: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral where Element: Weighted {}
```

> Type 'Set' does not conform to protocol
> 'ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral'

I don't understand why it doesn't conform to the protocol. Seems like it should conform at this stage.

**Bonus question**

```
extension ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral where Self: Collection, Element: Weighted {
```

How to make it extends not for all Collections, but only for Sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to make the `Weighted` protocol `public` as well as marking the init `public`.

```
public protocol Weighted: Hashable {
    associatedtype D: Hashable
    associatedtype W: Hashable
    var destination: D { get }
    var weight: W { get }
    init(destination: D, weight: W)
}

extension Set: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral where Element: Weighted {
    public init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (Element.D, Element.W)...) {
        self.init(elements.map(Element.init))
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! And what is wrong with the Second Approach? It's more important to me, because I'm going to make Set conform to ExpressibleByArrayLiteral protocol as well. But it's impossible to do with First Approach, because Set already conforms to this protocol in the standard library, and therefore I can not to conform it one more time, even with different constraint. So I would like to apply the Second Approach to this situation.

Comment: @Roman It will be easier to implement your own custom set type

Comment: Btw why would you create a set of dictionaries? Try structuring your data and create a set of those custom structures.

Comment: @Leo Dabus Yes, that's true. Actually I did it already. But I want to make another approaches work as well in order to learn swift :)

Comment: @Roman the issue with the 2nd approach is that you add a new method to `ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral`, not to `Set` (or even `Collection`) itself. You also won't be able to create such extension on `ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral` with `Set`, since `Set` is a generic `struct` and generic extensions are not (yet) supported by Swift. You'd need `extension ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral: Set<T>`, but that's not supported.

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm not creating a set of dictionaries :) I'm using literal dictionary to initialize struct Weighted first, and then I get set of Weighteds

Comment: @Roman You are going through the wrong path. A protocol it is not a type.

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes yes, I didn't mean that. I just have shortened explanation, but made misunderstanding instead, sorry. I meant than I get a Set of structs (they doesn't have names) which conform to Weighted.

Comment: @LeoDabus This line: self.init(elements.map(Element.init)) Look at it carefully. It has two inits :)

Comment: As I said it would be better to create your own set. This post might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887561/how-to-implement-a-mutable-ordered-set-generic-type-formerly-known-as-nsmutableo